# Duplicating a Sheet Based on Two Cells' Values

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button_8()
worksheets("Template_MM").Select
worksheets("Template_MM").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End Sub
```

I am working off of this code and want to copy a given worksheet based on cell values I have populated in cells B3 and B4 of the Home tab. The options for these cells are:

Home Tab cell B3: MM or PC

Home Tab cell B4: Green or Yellow

For example, if the user selects MM and Green I want the following code to run:

```
Sub Button_8()
worksheets("Template_MM_Green").Select
worksheets("Template_MM_Green").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End Sub
```

If the user selects MM and Yellow I want the following code to run:

```
Sub Button_8()
worksheets("Template_MM_Yellow").Select
worksheets("Template_MM_Yellow").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End Sub
```

I tried the following and am getting error messages:

```
Sub Button_8()
If worksheets("Home").Range("B3") Like "*MM*" And worksheets("Home").Range("B4") Like "*Yellow*" Then
THEN
worksheets("Template_Yellow_MM").Select
worksheets("Template_Yellow_MM").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `If...End If` ?

Comment: I tried the If...End If statement above and am getting error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Button_8()

If worksheets("Home").Range("B3") Like "*MM*" And worksheets("Home").Range("B4") Like "*Yellow*" Then
worksheets("Template_Yellow_MM").Select
worksheets("Template_Yellow_MM").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End If

If worksheets("Home").Range("B3") Like "*MM*" And worksheets("Home").Range("B4") Like "*Green*" Then
worksheets("Template_Green_MM").Select
worksheets("Template_Green_MM").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End If

If worksheets("Home").Range("B3") Like "*PC*" And worksheets("Home").Range("B4") Like "*Yellow*" Then
worksheets("Template_Yellow_PC").Select
worksheets("Template_Yellow_PC").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End If

If worksheets("Home").Range("B3") Like "*PC*" And worksheets("Home").Range("B4") Like "*Green*" Then
worksheets("Template_Green_PC").Select
worksheets("Template_Green_PC").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("Home").Range("B6")
Range("C3") = Sheets("Home").Range("B5")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

why not try to build worksheets as follows:
Sheets(" Template_ "& Sheets ("Home").Range("B3") & "_ " & Sheets("Home").Range("B4"))